# How do I save an Excel workbook to disk?

Tags: excel, file-io, save, office-interop

I am dynamically creating a Excel File that is displayed to the users upon creation, however I now need to also save the file onto the server.

How would I save it to a specific folder?

I have the following code

```
public void ExportMembers()
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);

        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;

        ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Site Id";

       //I create the rest of the cells here

        xla.Visible = true; //this displays the excel spreadsheet to the user

        //client id code is here

                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists("/Files/" + clientId + "/Excel"))
        { //if doesn't exist make folder

            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("/Files/" + clientId);

            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("/Files/" + clientId + "/Excel");

        }

 //save the xla as a file Here

    }
```

How do I save the spreadsheet on the server?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the Save method for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.save